# Arduino upgrading firmware

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

Hi I'm trying to upgrade firmware on my wifi shield by following the http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/WiFiShieldFirmwareUpgrading instructions for mac.  I was wondering what this means?

"Connect a jumper on the J3 connector, that put the shield in the programming mode. Then connect the USB cable to the shield USB mini socket"?

Answer (score 1):

A "jumper" is a little piece of metal (or a 0-ohm resistor) that connects two pads or pins together. So, create an electrical connection across J3. You will then be able to program the shield via USB.